# Question mark in alert's caption

Tags: error-message, messagebox

My doubt might seems a bit silly, but still...
Should the caption of an alert/prompt popup have question mark at the end?

For example, let's say that I have to issue a prompt to as for confirmation about whether to remove or not an item from the cart, I put the word "Confirm" in the title bar of the alert.

Should this be "confirm" or "confirm?", with a question mark?

Comment: Similar post on ux.stackexchange about this issue: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/what-are-the-best-guidelines-for-grammar-and-punctuation-in-alerts-and-user-mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not have a question mark in the caption because it is only a caption - a title or context in which the alert box is being shown.

The question, if there is one, will be asked in the text of the box. It is not the title's job to be doing the asking.

The examples in the [Microsoft user experience guidelines](http://scaley) do not use a question mark in the title, while the [OSX Human Interface UX guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html) (UI Elements / Dialogs / Alerts) specifically state 'no title'.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted a confirmation so no question mark or absolutely no caption if the framework allows so...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how may buttons and the button text. If you're asking a user to confirm something, shouldn't the user get a choice? Confirm and the system proceeds or don't confirm and you return to form/page.

My recommendation would be "Are you sure you want to remove from cart?" as your alert and   [NO] [Yes] for buttons. With the [YES] being the default selected button for key presses.

If your aler text is just 'Confirm' and you only have one button then no question mark and [OK] button unless you can change your text in button to 'Confirm'

Bottom line, if you user has a choice then its a question. If they don't then no question mark.

Comment: If I read the op's question correctly, it's about the *title bar* not the message box itself...

Comment: Fair point. That will teach me to read the question more carefully. Thx Roger.

Comment: Roger Attrill is right: I was asking about the caption.